# Extracting TCP application data from pcap file

Tags: networking, tcpdump, network-traffic, pcap, parsing

Given a `.pcap` (or similar) file, I'd like to select one TCP connection and dump both application data streams (the one *from* the other peer and the one *two* the other peer) into two separate files on disk.

Let's assume that I have a `.pcap` file that amongst other things I know contains a full TCP stream (from SYN to final FIN+ACK/RST) of a HTTP/1.1 plaintext connection. I would like to have two resulting files with the content. Ie. one file has

```
GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
host: foobar.com\r\n
\r\n
```

and the other file has

```
HTTP/1.1 200 ok\r\n
content-length: ...\r\n
... \r\n
\r\n
<html>...</html>
```

And I want this to be precisely the application data traffic that would've been seen/sent in user space (from `read`/`write`/`send/`recv`/...). What I want to do with this is dump some traffic and use that to test my parsers for a certain some network protocol. The parser should just be able to read one of those files and attempt to parse the data stream.

---

How could such a command line tool look? I'm not sure if this is super helpful but I thought it might make it clearer what I'm looking for if I also gave a usage example of an imaginary tool which can do this.
Let's call the imaginary tool (this is what I'm looking for) `tcp-stream-extract`. I'd like to call it with something like

```sh
### imaginary usage example of the tool that I'd like to find :)

# dump from 12345 to 23456
tcp-stream-extract \
    -i my-captured-packets.pcap
    -s 127.0.0.1:12345        \ # source address 127.0.0.1:12345
    -d 127.0.0.1:23456        \ # destination address 127.0.0.1:23456
    -t '2021-01-28 09:12:00Z' \ # the TCP conn was alive at that time
    -w from-port-12345-to-port-23456

# dump from 23456 to 12345
tcp-stream-extract \
    -i my-captured-packets.pcap
    -s 127.0.0.1:23456        \ # source address 127.0.0.1:12345
    -d 127.0.0.1:12345        \ # destination address 127.0.0.1:23456
    -t '2021-01-28 09:12:00Z' \ # the TCP conn was at that time
    -w from-port-23456-to-port-12345
```

Comment: You want `tcpflow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do this manually, you need to remove the headers of the encapsulating protocols. However, there are some subtleties to them and it may not be trivial:

- Ethernet (L2): The Ethernet header (14 bytes) may or may not include a 802.1q tag (in front of Ethertype, adding 4 bytes; `0x0800`=IPv4, `0x86dd`=IPv6, `0x8100`=802.1q tag) and the Ethernet payload may or may not be trailed by the FCS (4 bytes).
- IP (L3): A basic IPv4 header is 20 bytes, IPv6 uses 40 bytes. Each has options or extensions - check the *IHL* field for IPv4 (5 = no options), or the *Next Header* field for IPv6 (*6* indicates TCP, no extension). Any packet may be fragmented across several L2 frames (IPv4: *MF* is set or *Fragment Offset*>0; IPv6 uses extension header 44). Each first fragment includes L4 headers, later fragments do not.
- TCP (L4): The basic TCP segment header is 20 bytes, but it may also include options (*Data Offset*>5). TCP resorts out-of-order delivered segments (by *Sequence Number*), so you might need to buffer a considerable portion of the data. Segments may also arrive in duplicate.

I recommend using a proper tool like `tcpflow`, as @AlexD has suggested.

Comment: Thank you, `tcpflow` is exactly what I was looking for! Yes, tripping the headers of the various protocols is one thing, the most daunting task would've been handling out-of-order delivery & re-delivery of packets.

Comment: @JohannesWeiss Oh yes, forgot about that!